# Ionic 3 native geofence plugin not working on xcode 9 because of swift 3 not supported on geofence plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, swift3, ionic3, ionic-native

I am new in the ionic framework and I am using Ionic 3 **geofence** native plugin to build an ios and android app. The problem is on Android is working fine but on ios, it could not working. Because of geofence plugin not supported **swift 3** for now. What should I do now? Any advice will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this files https://github.com/ypelud/cordova-plugin-geofence/tree/master/src/ios, select "Swift Language Version" in "Swift 3"

Good luky